# Restoring from a single instance mongodb to an empty replica set

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, rackspace-cloud

I have a mongodb installed on windows server. I take regular backups of the data/db folder using Rackspace backup.

I created a deployment of a mongodb replica set with 3 ubuntu servers using Rackspace deployments. Now I want to move the data on windows to the empty replica set. How can I do it?

I tried copying the contents of data/db on windows to var/lib/mongodb on the primary replica set. It didn't work.

For some reason the var/lib/mongodb on the ubuntu machines does not contain data/db directory. When I create a new db the db files are created on var/lib/mongodb directory.

Comment: Wait can you reword your question to be clearer? What did you copy into var/lib/mongodb? The entire structure of /data/db or the contents of the /data/db folder? I am unsure of what you have tried so far, if you can make it clearer what you've done then we can help

Comment: I copied everything in the "data/db" directory

Comment: Can you show us the startup messages when you run mongod?

Comment: So is what I'm doing supposed to work? I guess it is and know you're trying to figure out what the problem is? Please give me a general answer, how do you take the data in a windows server and copy it to an empty replica set running on ubuntu? I'll figure out individual error messages etc. I just need a general how to guide

Comment: Is it supposed to work I have done this before myself, I literally make a new server, copy the /db/data to the data directory (in your case /var/lib/mongodb from your details) and start it with the replica flag and then start adding secondaries etc.

Comment: Ok in my case the replica sets were already in place before I copied the data directory. Could that make a difference? Yes the data folder seems to be var/lib/mongodb. I even tried creating a new database with the same name and overwriting the files with the files from the windows server. Do you think I should restart mongodb after I do this? Or is there a command I should run?

Comment: Yes definitely restart the mongod, you might get a problem that the primary is no longer a primary as such won't work, in which case you may have to recreate the replica set

Answer (score 1):

The difference in data directories is fine .. on Windows the default [`dbpath`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#dbpath) will be `c:\data\db`; the Ubuntu package sets the dbpath to `/var/lib/mongodb` instead.

Since you are starting with an empty replica set (and using a backup from a standalone server), the most straightforward approach would be to:

- Stop all the `mongod` servers for the replica set (you definitely don't want to copy data files directly into a running instance!).
- Remove any files that are already in the `/var/lib/mongodb` data directory.
- Copy the data files from your standalone MongoDB backup into `/var/lib/mongodb` on one of your replica set servers. This server will become your *primary* to set up the rest of the replica set.
- Start up this primary making sure to include a  [`replSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replSet) name in your configuration file. You may already have this set from your "empty" replica set that you already created.
- Run `rs.initiate()` in the `mongo` shell to create the initial configuration on the primary.
- Start up your additional servers as members of this replica set: they need the same `replSet` name configured.
- Use `rs.add(..)` to add your additional servers from the `mongo` shell on your primary. Assuming the add is successful (i.e. the `mongod`s can connect to each other), this will begin the process of initial sync (copying data from the primary) and the new hosts will become secondaries after they have finishing initial sync.

This is essentially the same steps as the [deploy a replica set tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#to-deploy-a-production-replica-set), except you are copying over your data first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be related to the configuration file of mongodb

locate the file `mongodb.conf` and edit the dbpath parameter, check if the path really exist, and if it doesn't create the missing directories. Also check permissions in that path

anyway i don't know if its the right way to just copy the datafiles in a new location, i guess you should use [mongo import/export](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/)

Comment: You should always use either a file copy or `mongodump`/`mongorestore` for [database backups](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backup/). Exporting to JSON can result in [`data type fidelity`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/#data-type-fidelity) issues when converting between BSON (the MongoDB storage format) and JSON. `mongodump` exports the full database and index definitions, whereas `mongoexport` does a collection at a time without any indexes. Import/export are intended for exchanging simple data with other systems, which is different from backup & restore.